# Android create tabs

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am trying to create app that has tabs which look like this one:
[image: https://lh5.ggpht.com/LQodTYJELKn4jmz_LfsYaM6yVrt2qpyGEtaUwAlqCXtY69ONkV7V_Qep3dXOCjlxQA=h900]

I know that it is possible to use fragments and tab indicators in actionbar but is this the best approach for this? I am using theme with noActionBar. I thought that I could use tabhost for this but I dont know if this is the best approach.

Thanks in forward

Comment: I used tabhost in one app and was working fine. Let's see what others ar saying.

Comment: tabhost must host activities under tabs? Or can I only create layouts there and then change layouts programatically from one activity?

Comment: You can host fragment under the tabs and attach two different layouts. Creating layouts and changing programmatically is not a good way.